# Value of pointer still available after function call?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
//needed so we can use the built in function strcpy
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
char* foo()
    {
        char* test="Hello";
        printf("value of test: %p\n",test);
        return test;

    }


    //why does this work? is test off the stack, but Hello in mem is still there?
    work=foo();
    printf("value of work after work has been initalized by foo(): %p\n",work);
    printf("%s\n",work);
}
```

In the above code, 'work=foo()', works I noticed that the value of 'test' and 'work' are the same. Meaning that they are pointing to the same point in memory, but after the function call 'test' is out of scope and not allowed to be accessed. Why is 'test' not allowed to be accessed, but its value/ memory location is? I'm assuming 'test' is not allowed to be accessed due to being off the stack after the function call? I'm new to pointers so if my terminology or anything is off please correct me.

Comment: It's probably because the compiler stores `"Hello"` in some global memory. However, don't rely on such lucky coincidences. What you are trying is cause for undefined behavior.

Comment: @RSahu No, it's not a lucky coincidence, this behavior(not counting the use of a nested function) is guaranteed. string literals have static storage duration.

Comment: Thank you, did not realize C did not support nested functions, and was unfamiliar with static memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nested functions are not standard c, it's an [extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html) of gcc, so your code wont always compile, and it does work because of the gcc extension.

The reason why that is true has nothing to do with nested functions, if you execute the following you will observe the exact same behavior

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *foo()
{
    char* test="Hello";
    printf("value of test: %p\n",test);
    return test;

}

int main()
{
    // why does this work? is test off the stack, but Hello in mem is still there?
    char *work = foo();

    printf("value of work after work has been initalized by foo(): %p\n",work);
    printf("%s\n",work);

    return 0;
}
```

the function `foo()` is returning the address to a static string which remains through the lifetime of the program.

I your instead create an array, you would return the address to a local variable which is not possible

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    char *foo()
    {
        char test[] = "Hello";

        printf("value of test: %p\n", test);
        printf("value of foo: %p\n", foo);

        return test;
    }

    // why does this work? is test off the stack, but Hello in mem is still there?
    char *work = foo();

    printf("value of work after work has been initalized by foo(): %p\n",work);
    printf("%s\n",work);

    return 0;
}
```

the compiler will issue a warning in the last case and `printf("%s\n",work);` would print garbage although `printf("value of work after work has been initalized by foo(): %p\n",work);` would print the same address, the data will be destroyed with the stack frame of `foo`.

Answer (score 2):

(As it has been noted, nested functions are not allowed in C language.)

Nevertheless, in C language string literals are object with static storage duration. They are not stored "on the stack", as you seem to incorrectly assume. They are stored in static memory, just like global variables.

The code of your `foo` function is equivalent to

```
static char unnamed_string_literal[] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };

char* foo()
{
  char* test = unnamed_string_literal;
  printf("value of test: %p\n", test);
  return test;
}
```

This is why value of the string literal `"Hello"` will always be available as long as your program runs. And every time you call your `foo`, you will get back exactly the same pointer value.

Answer (score 1):

Your foo() function is returning the static string "Hello" which is typically stored in the program text segment.

Since the actual string storage does not live on the stack it survives the function call.

The variable `test` whilst out of scope is just a pointer and since that pointer value is returned to the caller, the caller now has the location of the string storage.

Answer (score 0):

Nonstandard nested function definitions notwithstanding, the behavior you're seeing here is because the string constant "Hello" is part of the program executable, and is mapped into memory along with the program code when the program is executed.  The pointer simply holds the location in memory at runtime that the string is stored in.  That constant string is part of the program and doesn't spring into and out of existence like a stack variable would.  The stack variable is the *address* of "Hello", and it is passed to the calling stack via return value.

Comment: It's called static area same space with global variables.